# Docker or Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: git, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, developer-tools

I need to setup local dev environments for a team of 2 developers working in windows environments. Requirements for the dev environments are:

1. Must run an exact copy of the production server configuration.  Production server runs CentOS and a LEMP stack.
2. Each developers' branch of the GIT repository must run under the same LEMP stack as above.
3. The local dev system must have direct file access, no SCP or FTP.
4. The local LEMP stack must run under the same IP as the developers' workstations.

I am a bit old school used to working with very small teams of less than 5 developers.  Virtual Box and other vitalization systems as well as inexpensive remote VPS have served me well for many years.

I have explored switching to Docker, but see no benefit over Virtual Box VM's on Windows workstations.  It also requires a developer to SCP files in order to run under a LEMP stack.

I have setup WSL with CentOS and the production server configuration. With this configuration I can:

1. Clone a git repository to the local windows file system for direct file access.
2. Mount the repository in WSL.
3. Run the LEMP stack on the same IP as the workstation.

The WSL install can be gzipped, exported and imported into WSL so sharing and using the environment is fairly trivial.

I do have concerns over introducing an unfamiliar system that new developers on the team may not be accustomed to.

My question is:  what other features of Docker am I missing that could accomplish the same goals?

Answer (score 0):

For development with docker, use docker-compose.

There seem to be good materials here that is equivalent to the lemp stack:
https://github.com/frekans7/docker-compose-lemp

The idea of using docker for development is to let developers use their IDE installed on their own computer. A volume is mounted to the docker server images in order to serve their code. They can access the webserver or even phpMyAdmin directly from their own internet browser.

The cool thing for the maintainer is that if you want to update mysql/mariadb for instance, you just have to edit the docker-compose.yml file, and change the version. Then tell the developers you changed the version. They restart the docker-compose stack and its done, updated.

Comment: Thank you.  Will this allow the Docker image to share an IP with the host Windows system?

Comment: docker-compose-lemp is configured to map ports from the containers which are on a private docker network to the host. So the ip of the containers is localhost. if you want to define ip for your containers which I won't recommend if you are making a development environment, you could have a look at the docker documentation on networks. here is a good example of configuration for static networks https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-static-ip-container-linux-to-mac/42513/2